# Connect a servo to explorer hat

Tags: servo, explorer-hat

trying to get a servo controller from my raspberry pi with a [piminori explorer hat](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/explorer-hat) and [servoblaster](https://github.com/richardghirst/PiBits/tree/master/ServoBlaster).
When I use one of the GPIO port which connect to the LEDs and touch with the yellow control wire of the servo the right connector of the LED, everything works fine.
When I try to do the same with one of the outputs, I do not succeed.

I do understand that the outputs are only capable of shorting the signal to groun, so I used a 10k pull up resistor. A LED shows me that this seems to work, but my servo does not move.

Here is my setup:

[image: Servo connected to Explorer Hat]

and yes - it seems that the output will be inverted, so in order to use servoblaster, you have to type

```
cd PiBits/ServoBlaster/user
sudo ./servod --p1pins=7,31 --invert
echo 1=100 > /dev/servoblaster
```

pin 7 is the blue LED, pin 31 should be output 1

Any idea?

PS: we have a discussion going on about this problem in the pimoroni forum: http://forums.pimoroni.com/t/trying-to-connect-a-servo-to-explorer-hat/1176

Comment: I suspect you'll have to ask pimoroni to get an answer.  Perhaps the outputs can't be switched fast enough.